# VB equivalent code to C#; List of Strings

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, list, integer

What is the equivalent of the following code in C#?

```
Dim intValidChars As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() { Asc("0"), Asc("1"), Asc("2"), Asc("3"), Asc("4"), Asc("5"), Asc("6"), Asc("7"), Asc("8"), Asc("9"), _
                                                              Asc("A"), Asc("B"), Asc("C"), Asc("D"), Asc("E"), Asc("F"), Asc("G"), Asc("H"), Asc("I"), Asc("J")})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: @AlexB. You should try it on this sample.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas I did. And it worked instantly.

Comment: @AlexB. Try to compile that - you'll find no 'strings' class in Microsoft.VisualBasic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add  the VB DLL reference to the project (`import Microsoft.VisualBasic;`).

Try this code:

```
List<int> intValidChars = new List<int>(new int[] {
    Strings.Asc("0"),
    Strings.Asc("1"),
    Strings.Asc("2"),
    Strings.Asc("3"),
    Strings.Asc("4"),
    Strings.Asc("5"),
    Strings.Asc("6"),
    Strings.Asc("7"),
    Strings.Asc("8"),
    Strings.Asc("9"),
    Strings.Asc("A"),
    Strings.Asc("B"),
    Strings.Asc("C"),
    Strings.Asc("D"),
    Strings.Asc("E"),
    Strings.Asc("F"),
    Strings.Asc("G"),
    Strings.Asc("H"),
    Strings.Asc("I"),
    Strings.Asc("J")
});
```

Comment: To use the `String.Asc` you have to add the VB DLL reference to the project. You should mention that in answer.

Comment: yes, i edit my post @CoderofCode

Comment: Please don´t answer to this kind of questions since it is clearly a code writing/translating request. Do not encourage others to also ask those question!

Comment: Thank you, my problem was with adding the reference since it was giving me error on Strings.Asc :)